# How do I download iOS 8.0 or newer for iPhone 4s

Tags: iphone, ios, software-update

I have an iPhone 4s that is running iOS 7.04 and won't update. It requires iOS 8.0 or newer to install any apps.

**How can I download iOS 8.0 or newer on my iPhone 4s?**